# Find column by name and convert it vba

Tags: excel, vba

How can I find in vba column by name ex. "Test1" and convert whole column to number format?

as far i manage to find the cell:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="Test1")
```

Comment: `worksheets("Sheet1").cells.find(what:"Test1").entirecolumn.numberformat = "0.00"` or whatever [format](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) you want.

Comment: Note that by setting the number format to a cell, you don't convert the data. You just tell Excel how to display it. If you have strings in that cell, they remain strings.

Comment: Yes, but that might resolve issue when those numbers are exported to csv. Any other ideas how to directly convert to format numbers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = FindColumn("Test1")
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        r.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    End If

End Sub

Public Function FindColumn(HeaderName As String) As Range

    Dim FndCol As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set FndCol = .Cells.Find(HeaderName, .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not FndCol Is Nothing Then
            Set FindColumn = FndCol.EntireColumn
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### Data Column Number Format

- This solution will print the range addresses at the various stages of the code to the `Immediate window` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).
- For example, in the range `A1:J10` containing data, if cell `C1` is equal to `Test1`, it will apply the number format to the range `C2:C10`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub applyColumnNumberFormat()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const HeaderRow As Long = 1
    Const Header As String = "Test1"
    Const nFormat As String = "#.00"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = ws.Rows(HeaderRow) ' Header Row Range
    Debug.Print "Header Row Range:    " & hrg.Address(0, 0)
    
    Dim hCell As Range ' Header Cell Range
    Set hCell = hrg.Find(Header, hrg.Cells(hrg.Cells.Count), _
        xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    
    If Not hCell Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Header Cell Address: " & hCell.Address(0, 0)
        
        Dim lCell As Range ' Last Non-Empty Cell Range
        Set lCell = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        Debug.Print "Last Non-Empty Cell: " & lCell.Address(0, 0)
        
        Dim drg As Range ' Destination Range - Occupied Cells Below the Header
        Set drg = hCell.Resize(lCell.Row - hCell.Row).Offset(1)
        Debug.Print "Destination Range:   " & drg.Address(0, 0)
        
        drg.NumberFormat = nFormat
    
    Else
    
        Debug.Print "Header '" & Header & "' not found."
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code assumes your column headings are on row 1.
The **Find** function returns a range object. You can use the **Column** property of the range to identify the column you want to format.

```
Dim r As Range
Dim col As Integer
        
Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Find(What:="Test")
If r Is Nothing Then
    'Column heading not found
Else
    col = r.Column
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(col).NumberFormat = "0.00"
End If
```

Comment: Note that `Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(col).NumberFormat = "0.00"` can be simplified to `r.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "0.00"`